# idea: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classnotfoundexception

I have the code:

```
public class GuaranteedDeadlock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] arr = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    }
}
```

it produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GuaranteedDeadlock
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

[image]
module settings:
[image]

Looks like I configured idea a bit wrong, please correct me.

Comment: What is the package name. Try Including `package your-pkg-name` at the starting(Before the Imports) and run it then.

Comment: @Shashwat As you can see I put code into src folder. I don't have any package

Comment: I think you have a package. I deduce this from the `concurrency` folder before the `src` one. Try adding `package concurrency` to the top of the `GuaranteedDeadlock` class

Comment: @Shashwat doesn't help me

Comment: What are your run configurations. To Find, them, Click on the rectangle beside the `green run button`. Make Sure Your `Main` class is set Correctly.